# How to properly set a function that returns the difference in years in python?

Tags: python, function, date, datetime

I am trying to program a function that returns me the difference in years given an specific date format,
which is: `"01/%m/%Y"`:

Here's the code I am using:

```
import datetime as datetime

###################### function to return difference in years ####################

def years_between(start_year, end_year):
    start_year = datetime.strptime(start_year, "01/%m/%Y")
    end_year = datetime.strptime(end_year, "01/%m/%Y")
    return abs((end_year - start_year).years)
```

When tested it returns:

```
years_between("01/10/1900", "01/10/2000")

AttributeError: 'datetime.timedelta' object has no attribute 'years'
```

Expected function output would be an integer, in the above case would be `100`

Is there any other way to correct this function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from datetime import datetime

def years_between(start_year, end_year):
    start_year = datetime.strptime(start_year, "%d/%m/%Y")
    end_year = datetime.strptime(end_year, "%d/%m/%Y")
    return abs(end_year.year - start_year.year)


print(years_between("01/10/1901", "01/10/2000"))
```

Comment: Thanks @Leemosh! runs perfectly